# Dump customers using magerun issue

Tags: database, magento-1

I used this command  to dump all of the customers:

```
n98-magerun db:dump --strip="@customers"
```

This works fine, but this generates me a file where I have the create/drop queries. I don't need that. Is there a way to generates only insert queries ?

Thx

Comment: This commands dump a complete database. If you use the strip option, it removes data from dump. In your case it's removing the customer data. It's the opposite of your intend. You can use `mysqldump` with `--no-create-info` option.